# jHTMLArea: disable Browser spellcheck

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, spell-checking, jhtmlarea

I'm using jHTMLArea as wysiwyg editor. And when Chrome spellchecking is turned on, text is underlined with red waved lines. How to disable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by setting spellcheck=false to body of inner iframe of jHtmlArea.

Answer (score 0):

With HTML5 you can do this with `spellcheck=false`.
You must add this to the `textarea` of your jHTMLArea.

With jQuery you can do that with

```
$("textarea").attr('spellcheck', false)
```

Comment: jHtmlArea creates iframe with another html page

Comment: you can not manipulate content in an iframe. But when you have access to the page displayed in the iframe you can set it there